# Select maximum of groups

Tags: mysql, group-by

we have a table as the following which contains an order status:

```
history
---------------------------------
order_id    status    date
  25         1        2014-10-01
  25         3        2014-10-02
  26         1        2014-10-01
  27         2        2014-10-01
  26         4        2014-10-03
```

I need to select the order_id of columns with a specified status, but it has to be the latest status. 
This is possible with the group by function:

```
SELECT status, order_id, MAX(date) 
FROM history GROUP BY order_id HAVING status = 4 OR status = 2
```

But this is not suitable for me, because I ONLY want the order_id, because this is a part of a subquery (SELECT ... WHERE order_id IN ([above query])). However, MySQL doesn't allow this. 
Is there any alternative way to solve this?

Comment: what about `GROUP BY(status)` and use `WHERE` instead of `HAVING`

Comment: recent one will have greater auto increment id column, you can go with this logic

Comment: Given that this question is asked and (correctly) answered EVERY. SINGLE. DAY. in SO, I find it a little depressing that a) it needs to be asked yet again, and b) that so many respondents are able to provide incorrect answers. I feel that there is scope to improve the mechanics of SO in this respect.

Comment: @Strawberry Question was not clear initially and later user cleared in comment under one answer. everyone answer by their thought and perception. if it's wrong then negative marking is there.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is a variation of the standard groupwise max problem, widely discussed here and elsewhere - and even with its own dedicated chapter in the mysql manual.

The standard response to the standard problem is the employment of an uncorrelated subquery, as follows...

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM history x 
  JOIN  
     ( SELECT order_id, MAX(date) max_date FROM history GROUP BY order_id ) y 
    ON y.order_id = x.order_id 
   AND y.max_date = x.date;
```

Your problem appears to be more complicated because of the additional requirement. However, this is a red herring. The correct answer using this method then is as follows...

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM history x 
  JOIN  
     ( SELECT order_id, MAX(date) max_date FROM history GROUP BY order_id ) y 
    ON y.order_id = x.order_id 
   AND y.max_date = x.date 
 WHERE status IN (2,4);
```

Answer (score -1):

use SELF JOIN

```
SELECT h1.`order_id` FROM `history` h1
LEFT JOIN `history` h2 
ON (h1.`order_id`= h2.`order_id` AND h1.`status` > h2.`status`)
-- WHERE h1.status IN (1,2,3) < -- here you can use your status condition
GROUP BY h1.`order_id`
```

[Reference](http://goo.gl/rdR7P)

Comment: I voted down. Your solution is flawed, and so will return unpredictable and erroneous results. With one ('hack') exception, this is always the case when GROUP BY is used in the absence of any aggregating functions. See my comment above - although the reference you provide (for a different RDBMS) also explains this!

Comment: @Strawberry I have checked this solution on my end and working very well, OP wants a single select and thats's the only solution i come up with. tell me what is the exact issue? have you run this?

Comment: The reference you cite provides a reasonable explanation. But putting that to one side, you select only one column, and you group by that column, so how's that going to be useful? The OP wants `order_id`,    `status`, and `date`!!

Comment: I appreciate that the OP has not expressed themselves well in this regard, but it's clear from their query that they want all columns. Also logic dictates that this must be so. Otherwise the query could just as well be `SELECT DISTINCT order_id FROM history WHERE status IN (2,4)`

Comment: @Strawberry you haven't focus on what he is asking. DISTINCT will return the first row whereas OP wants the second row ( with latest status ). please test yourself with my query. EOD

Comment: I know what the OP is after; that's why I supplied an answer that satisfies the requirement.